# Is it possible to transfer the activities from one stream to another [within same replica]?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are having multisite clearcase environment.

Within a site we are having multiple streams.

Is it possible to transfer an activity from one stream to another [wtihin same replica]?

Comment: though you have got the answer, it would be interesting to know why you would want to do this

Comment: @Pulak Agrawal: by mistake one of the same team member started working on different stream and other people in team has to wait till he deliver his ativities.

Comment: In that case what is the resolution you are applying ? Delivering activities/baselines from this team member's stream to your default (Integration ??) stream or something like that ?

Comment: @Pulak Agrawal Yes ,we are delivering to integration stream then rebasing in other people development stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-site or not, an activity is linked to a **stream** (you cannot "move" an activity from one stream to another)

See "[About activities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_rmt_delvr_ucm_cq_ccms.htm)":

[image: activity]

> **The activity object belongs to a single stream and cannot be moved to another stream**.
>   (If you assign one or more versions to the wrong activity or if you create new activities to better represent your work, you can assign the versions to a different activity.)

Multi-site allows for ownership (called "mastership", see "[About deliveries in a Rational ClearCase MultiSite project](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_deliver_MultiSite_proj.htm)") transfer between *sites*, but it is still attached to the same stream.